# PDF version of the Ardour manual

Tags: daw

Is "The Ardour Manual" (http://manual.ardour.org/introducing-ardour/creating-music-with-ardour/) available in PDF format somewhere?

I've only found a thread from 2007 concerning this matter (https://community.ardour.org/node/1188#comment-17015), however, the link http://www[.]ardourmanual.blogspot.com.es/ is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this link is useful: http://carlh.net/ardour/manual/ardour.pdf
Which version are you looking for?